# Invalid byte sequences when hashing text in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to hash some strings (`character varying`) in Postgres, but it fails on some strings.

This works:

```sql
select encode(sha256('abc'), 'hex') as hash
```

> ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad

But this fails:

```sql
select encode(sha256('\/'), 'hex') as hash
```

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bytea LINE 3: select
> encode(sha256('/'), 'hex') as hash
> ^ SQL state: 22P02 Character: 24

How can I make my hashing work with any string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\/'` is not a valid `bytea` literal. Use `convert_to`:

```
SELECT encode(sha256(convert_to('\/', 'UTF8')), 'hex') AS hash;
```